# Trying to change the url of a new site

Tags: multisite

I installed Wordpress a year ago and have been using it as a single user quite contentedly.  Recently I was asked if I could let someone else setup a blog under my site.

Multisite was the answer and aside from the current problem it works well.

When I originally set it up I figured this day might come... so my structure is mydomain.com/blogs/myuser

My intention was to have new user's blog at mydomain.com/blogs/newuser but instead it's turning up at mydomain.com/blogs/myuser/newuser

I've seen a number of ideas floating about regarding renaming and database editing.  I tried to manually move mydomain.com/blogs/myuser/newuser to mydomain.com/blogs/newuser but only recieved 404 errors after editing the database.

Comment: Stephen I don't think you need to rewrite anything in the DB. Explore what you can do with a custom permalink structure or create a rewrite rule for your htaccess file to simply produce the final URL structure that you want.  I'm no expert on either but have used both to achieve similar goals as what you describe.

Comment: @jdm2112 This is my fallback plan, I have to refresh myself on rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the WP Codex section on permalinks, I'm confident you can achieve the URL structure that you want with a custom permalink structure.  Full list of options and lots of examples in the Codex [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: In fact you cannot achieve this with permalinks.  As you can see in your link the base path is non-editable.

Comment: My apologies Stephen. I believe I misunderstood the path problem.  Am I right that your WPMS network lives at mydomain.com/blogs/myuser/? I think I assumed (always a bad idea) that your WP network root was mydomain.com/blogs/

Comment: Yes, I believe my network is living at /blogs/myuser and I need to move the whole darn thing somehow.  Using the site link and changing to a new url does not do anything (because I'm just point it at a new empty directory of course)

Comment: I see.  Then I did misunderstood the details.  Sorry about that.  I think the simplest route at this point then is a rewrite condition/rule.