# How can I write a rewrite rule to appear to move a multisite?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

As we concluded in my question about [trying to change the url of a multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/145761/32739) the simplest solution might be to add a rewrite rule, since it is infact only the end result that I'm concerned about here.

I attempted to add a rewrite rule in a fairly simple way that didn't seem to work so I'm back to ask for your help.  I think this is relevant here because the rewrite rule itself isn't complicated, but rather how it's interacting with WordPress that's daunting my efforts.

The current directory structure looks something like this

```
r.info
/
+- blogs +- th
         |   - .htaccess
         |  + - wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes
         +- st
```

The original idea was that the new multisite would go into st giving /r.info/blogs/st but it turns out that the url considers /r.info/blogs/th to be base, resulting in /r.info/blogs/th/st

At the moment there is no .htaccess file in any directory, except as noted above.  I don't imagine that will stay the way it is for lots of obvious reasons.

```
-bash-3.2$ cat .htaccess
#RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
#RewriteRule    /blogs/st/(.*)$    /blogs/th/st/$1    [NC]

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

        # Text
        AddType text/css .css
        AddType application/x-javascript .js
        AddType text/html .html .htm
        AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
        AddType text/plain .txt
        AddType text/xml .xml

        # Image
        AddType image/gif .gif
        AddType image/x-icon .ico
        AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
        AddType image/png .png
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz

        # Video
        AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
        AddType video/avi .avi
        AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
        AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
        AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe

        # PDF
        AddType application/pdf .pdf

        # Flash
        AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf

        # Font
        AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
        AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
        AddType application/x-font-otf .otf

        # Audio
        AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
        AddType audio/ogg .ogg
        AddType audio/wav .wav
        AddType audio/wma .wma

        # Zip/Tar
        AddType application/x-tar .tar
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
        AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On

        # Text
        ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
        ExpiresByType text/html A3600
        ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
        ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
        ExpiresByType text/xml A3600

        # Image
        ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000

        # Video
        ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
        ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000

        # PDF
        ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000

        # Flash
        ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000

        # Font
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000

        # Audio
        ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
        ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000

        # Zip/Tar
        ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
        ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|htm|html|rtf|rtx|txt|xml|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|svg|svgz|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|mov|qt|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|pdf|swf|ttf|ttc|eot|otf|mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma|tar|gz|gzip|zip)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set Pragma "public"
                Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
                Header unset ETag
        </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|pdf|swf|ttf|ttc|eot|otf)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header unset Set-Cookie
        </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /blogs/th/st/
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
        RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<Files "wp-config.php">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
# END wtwp_security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/th/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried several variations of the RewriteRule you see commented out, which I left in case placement is an issue eg:

```
RewriteRule    ^r.info/blogs/st/$    r.info/blogs/th/st/
```

etc.

Requests to the url in the rewrite returns a 404 error but accessing the undesired url directly works just fine.

Comment: Quick comment here - you should have an .htaccess file in your Wordpress root directory unless permalinks are not in use.  That file is what Wordpress will reference when producing your final output URLs.  To solve your challenge, I would think a rewrite condition that checks for the undesired folder nesting before modifying the URL.  I will find a write up and that and post for you momentarily.

Comment: @jdm2112 To be clear here: blogs/th is my wordpress root directory, which is at the heart of my whole problem :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will create an .htaccess file automatically if you are using Permalinks.  There will not be an .htaccess file if Permalinks are set to default, unless another component has created it.  WordPress will only look to the one single instance of .htaccess in the WP root (unless you specifically setup a separate sub-folder install) and ignore any versions in sub folders.

Try testing for the folder layers you want to remove with a `RewriteCond` check and then rewrite those up to root or up one layer, whichever is your goal.

Something like this should produce what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
#
# stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder2/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

More details about this approach [here](https://drupal.org/node/30334) and [from Apache directly](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: I don't think I followed sufficiently, or some complexity or interaction with the wordpress parts of the .htaccess I displayed are causing this to not correctly rewrite... `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/th/st/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]` give a 500 error when accessing the full url and a 404 when using the shorter.